# Is there a shorter way to write ISPICKVAL for multiple values?

Tags: formula

I'm hitting my character limit for an OR formula and it's because I have to write out each ISPICKVAL statement:

```
ISPICKVAL(SHIFT_MEDIA__Type__c,"x"),
ISPICKVAL(SHIFT_MEDIA__Type__c,"y"),
ISPICKVAL(SHIFT_MEDIA__Type__c,"z"),....
```

Comment: this in future release https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tbI    https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Boz1AAC

Comment: Jared .. is your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. Use `TEXT` to use picklist value as Text and use `CASE` to check each value..

```
Case(TEXT(SHIFT_MEDIA__Type__c),
   "X","X", 
   "Y", "Y", 
   "Z", "Z", 
   "A"
)
```

So like [@crop1645](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2602/crop1645) said no need to use `TEXT` function.

```
Case(SHIFT_MEDIA__Type__c,
       "X","X", 
       "Y", "Y", 
       "Z", "Z", 
       "A"
    )
```

[There is Idea posted on IdeaExchange to Use Picklist fields with the CASE()](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tbI)

Comment: (1) `TEXT(..)` is unnecessary as CASE supports picklists; (2) CASE is also much less compiled character intensive then multiple ISPICKVAL

Comment: Ohh @crop1645 Thanks for heads up.. So basically this is the best option without text ex. `Case(SHIFT_MEDIA__Type__c,
   "X","X", 
   "Y", "Y", 
   "Z", "Z", 
   "A"
)`  is it?